# openframeworks - how to fade a video in and out

Tags: c++, video, openframeworks

Hi I'm using openframeworks ofVideoPlayer() function :

http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoPlayer.html

I've created a video, but I want to fade it out when it is done. Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getPosition()`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoPlayer.html#getPosition) and [`getDuration()`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoPlayer.html#getDuration) functions of the ofVideoPlayer to determine when you're near the end of the video. When you want to start fading out the video, start setting the current color to whatever you want to fade to. You'll probably want to use an interpolation function like [`ofLerp()`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/math/ofMath.html#ofLerp) to create a smooth transition.

If you want to fade out with alpha, make sure you've enabled alpha blending with [`ofEnableAlphaBlending()`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofGraphics.html#ofEnableAlphaBlending).

Comment: Thanks - I tried the alpha blending with a rectangle drawn over the video but it just instantly blacks out the video. I think what I'm confused about is "start setting the current color to whatever you want to fade to" - what am I setting the color of? The video?

Comment: You can use `ofSetColor()` to change the current global color. It will have an effect on any subsequent drawing. Note that you should set it to white (`ofSetColor(255)`) before drawing the video, as it will be tinted otherwise. Drawing a rectangle over the video will also work, but you should set a color with alpha to control the blend amount (and use `ofEnableAlphaBlending()` to enable blending)